# partition tuple of numbers into chunks

Tags: python, partitioning

Let's say I have many video files, and I'd like to split them into groupings of approximately 60 minutes (it would be okay if the grouping is 10% over 60, but no larger). They do not have to be equal sized groupings. I guess another way to state this, is I'm looking for the fewest groupings which sum <= 66.

So an ideal example would be:

```
group(59, 5, 20, 20, 1, 7, 33, 22, 20)
```

would return

```
( (59, 1), (20, 20, 20), (5, 33, 22), (7,) )
```

I cannot think of how to do this without trying random combinations, and I don't see that scaling well.

Thanks!

Comment: You could try sorting your list and taking from each end based on how much you have left to go.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should try to post code that you tried and didn't work, and we'll help you fix it or improve it. Asking for a strategy to perform a programming task is not exactly what the site is meant for. Avoid posting this kind of question in the future.

Comment: @MarkSnyder: That won't give the optimal solution though - think eg. `(1, 2, 2, 57, 58)`. @helium_moose: You might want to take a look at "multiple subset sum problem". (I don't think it's a perfect match, but you could eg. increase the number of bins until you get a solution. If the solution doesn't have to be optimal, a greedy algorithm, like what Mark Snyder suggested, will definitely be a faster solution)

Comment: Is this not just the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)? It's well trodden ground and there are many solutions available on the web.

Comment: What about the other combinations whose total length is less than 66? e.g. (1,), (5,), etc.? Your desired output isn't consistent with the criteria you describe

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the combinations of elements whose total sum is less or equal 66, sorted by number of elements (ascending) and by total sum (descending).

It works by creating the combinations using a simple counter, considering the bits of its binary representation. A bit set to one means that element of the group is present in the combination.

Note: it still goes through all the possible combinations, but with a small memory footprint. It is by no means the best possible solution, mathematically speaking.

```
from operator import itemgetter

def combins(group, max_len=66):
    for n in range(1, 2**len(group)):
        n_bin = bin(n)[:1:-1]
        comb = tuple(l for l, c in zip(group, n_bin) if c == '1')
        s = sum(comb)
        if s <= max_len:
            yield comb, len(comb), -s

group = (59, 5, 20, 20, 1, 7, 33, 22, 20)
sorted_subs = sorted(combins(group), key=itemgetter(1, 2))
clean_subs = [c for c, _, _ in sorted_subs]
print(clean_subs)
```

produces

```
[(59,), (33,), (22,), (20,), (20,), (20,), (7,), (5,), (1,), (59, 7), (59, 5), (59, 1), (33, 22), (20, 33), (20, 33), (33, 20), (20, 22), (20, 22), (22, 20), (20, 20), (7, 33), (20, 20), (20, 20), (5, 33), (1, 33), (7, 22), (20, 7), (20, 7), (5, 22), (7, 20), (5, 20), (5, 20), (5, 20), (1, 22), (20, 1), (20, 1), (1, 20), (5, 7), (1, 7), (5, 1), (59, 5, 1), (20, 20, 22), (7, 33, 22), (20, 22, 20), (20, 22, 20), (20, 7, 33), (20, 7, 33), (5, 33, 22), (20, 20, 20), (7, 33, 20), (5, 20, 33), (5, 20, 33), (5, 33, 20), (1, 33, 22), (20, 1, 33), (20, 1, 33), (1, 33, 20), (20, 7, 22), (20, 7, 22), (7, 22, 20), (20, 20, 7), (5, 20, 22), (5, 20, 22), (20, 7, 20), (20, 7, 20), (5, 22, 20), (5, 20, 20), (5, 7, 33), (5, 20, 20), (5, 20, 20), (20, 1, 22), (20, 1, 22), (1, 22, 20), (20, 20, 1), (1, 7, 33), (20, 1, 20), (20, 1, 20), (5, 1, 33), (5, 7, 22), (5, 20, 7), (5, 20, 7), (5, 7, 20), (1, 7, 22), (20, 1, 7), (20, 1, 7), (5, 1, 22), (1, 7, 20), (5, 20, 1), (5, 20, 1), (5, 1, 20), (5, 1, 7), (5, 20, 7, 33), (5, 20, 7, 33), (5, 20, 20, 20), (5, 7, 33, 20), (20, 20, 1, 22), (1, 7, 33, 22), (20, 1, 22, 20), (20, 1, 22, 20), (20, 1, 7, 33), (20, 1, 7, 33), (5, 1, 33, 22), (20, 20, 1, 20), (1, 7, 33, 20), (5, 20, 1, 33), (5, 20, 1, 33), (5, 1, 33, 20), (5, 20, 7, 22), (5, 20, 7, 22), (5, 7, 22, 20), (5, 20, 20, 7), (5, 20, 7, 20), (5, 20, 7, 20), (20, 1, 7, 22), (20, 1, 7, 22), (1, 7, 22, 20), (20, 20, 1, 7), (5, 20, 1, 22), (5, 20, 1, 22), (20, 1, 7, 20), (20, 1, 7, 20), (5, 1, 22, 20), (5, 20, 20, 1), (5, 1, 7, 33), (5, 20, 1, 20), (5, 20, 1, 20), (5, 1, 7, 22), (5, 20, 1, 7), (5, 20, 1, 7), (5, 1, 7, 20), (5, 20, 1, 7, 33), (5, 20, 1, 7, 33), (5, 20, 20, 1, 20), (5, 1, 7, 33, 20), (5, 20, 1, 7, 22), (5, 20, 1, 7, 22), (5, 1, 7, 22, 20), (5, 20, 20, 1, 7), (5, 20, 1, 7, 20), (5, 20, 1, 7, 20)]
```

In case you wanted the best fit for any given size, the results can be grouped by size

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

combs_by_size = defaultdict(list)
for comb, size, _ in sorted(combins(group), key=itemgetter(1, 2)):
    combs_by_size[size].append(comb)
pprint(combs_by_size)
```

which produces

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {1: [(59,), (33,), (22,), (20,), (20,), (20,), (7,), (5,), (1,)],
             2: [(59, 7),
                 (59, 5),
                 (59, 1),
                 (33, 22),
                 (20, 33),
                 (20, 33),
                 (33, 20),
                 (20, 22),
                 (20, 22),
                 (22, 20),
                 (20, 20),
                 (7, 33),
                 (20, 20),
                 (20, 20),
                 (5, 33),
                 (1, 33),
                 (7, 22),
                 (20, 7),
                 (20, 7),
                 (5, 22),
                 (7, 20),
                 (5, 20),
                 (5, 20),
                 (5, 20),
                 (1, 22),
                 (20, 1),
                 (20, 1),
                 (1, 20),
                 (5, 7),
                 (1, 7),
                 (5, 1)],
             3: [(59, 5, 1),
                 (20, 20, 22),
                 (7, 33, 22),
                 (20, 22, 20),
                 (20, 22, 20),
                 (20, 7, 33),
                 (20, 7, 33),
                 (5, 33, 22),
                 (20, 20, 20),
                 (7, 33, 20),
                 (5, 20, 33),
                 (5, 20, 33),
                 (5, 33, 20),
                 (1, 33, 22),
                 (20, 1, 33),
                 (20, 1, 33),
                 (1, 33, 20),
                 (20, 7, 22),
                 (20, 7, 22),
                 (7, 22, 20),
                 (20, 20, 7),
                 (5, 20, 22),
                 (5, 20, 22),
                 (20, 7, 20),
                 (20, 7, 20),
                 (5, 22, 20),
                 (5, 20, 20),
                 (5, 7, 33),
                 (5, 20, 20),
                 (5, 20, 20),
                 (20, 1, 22),
                 (20, 1, 22),
                 (1, 22, 20),
                 (20, 20, 1),
                 (1, 7, 33),
                 (20, 1, 20),
                 (20, 1, 20),
                 (5, 1, 33),
                 (5, 7, 22),
                 (5, 20, 7),
                 (5, 20, 7),
                 (5, 7, 20),
                 (1, 7, 22),
                 (20, 1, 7),
                 (20, 1, 7),
                 (5, 1, 22),
                 (1, 7, 20),
                 (5, 20, 1),
                 (5, 20, 1),
                 (5, 1, 20),
                 (5, 1, 7)],
             4: [(5, 20, 7, 33),
                 (5, 20, 7, 33),
                 (5, 20, 20, 20),
                 (5, 7, 33, 20),
                 (20, 20, 1, 22),
                 (1, 7, 33, 22),
                 (20, 1, 22, 20),
                 (20, 1, 22, 20),
                 (20, 1, 7, 33),
                 (20, 1, 7, 33),
                 (5, 1, 33, 22),
                 (20, 20, 1, 20),
                 (1, 7, 33, 20),
                 (5, 20, 1, 33),
                 (5, 20, 1, 33),
                 (5, 1, 33, 20),
                 (5, 20, 7, 22),
                 (5, 20, 7, 22),
                 (5, 7, 22, 20),
                 (5, 20, 20, 7),
                 (5, 20, 7, 20),
                 (5, 20, 7, 20),
                 (20, 1, 7, 22),
                 (20, 1, 7, 22),
                 (1, 7, 22, 20),
                 (20, 20, 1, 7),
                 (5, 20, 1, 22),
                 (5, 20, 1, 22),
                 (20, 1, 7, 20),
                 (20, 1, 7, 20),
                 (5, 1, 22, 20),
                 (5, 20, 20, 1),
                 (5, 1, 7, 33),
                 (5, 20, 1, 20),
                 (5, 20, 1, 20),
                 (5, 1, 7, 22),
                 (5, 20, 1, 7),
                 (5, 20, 1, 7),
                 (5, 1, 7, 20)],
             5: [(5, 20, 1, 7, 33),
                 (5, 20, 1, 7, 33),
                 (5, 20, 20, 1, 20),
                 (5, 1, 7, 33, 20),
                 (5, 20, 1, 7, 22),
                 (5, 20, 1, 7, 22),
                 (5, 1, 7, 22, 20),
                 (5, 20, 20, 1, 7),
                 (5, 20, 1, 7, 20),
                 (5, 20, 1, 7, 20)]})
```

So taking the first element of the list of a given size gives you the best fit for such size, e.g.

```
print(combs_by_size[3][0])
```

gives

```
(59, 5, 1)
```

As you might notice, the output combinations only show the values as they are, so elements of the group cannot be told apart if they have the same value, e.g. the number 20 appears multiple times in the sample group.
In order to know which 20 it is, we would have to add an attribute next to the value, maybe as a tuple of `(filename, length)` instead of `length` only as it is now.