# Splitting a tuple into "optimal" groups

Tags: python

I'm doing some probability testing for some in progress ttrpgs and have run into a dice mechanic that is extremely difficult to model probabilities for. I'm the guy on the team with (admittedly minimal) programming experience, but I've reached the end of what I can figure out how to do with this one.

Essentially:
I am given a tuple of positive and negative integers (there will almost always be more positives and the positives will have a higher average absolute value) and two additional integers, X and Y. I then need to optimally split the tuple into X groups with the following rules:

- The goal is to create the maximum number of groups whose sum is >= Y (a "success")
- A group whose sum is negative will *remove* a success. (So if X is 3 and Y is 5 and we have two groups >= 5 and one group that is negative we have 1 success)
- The original tuple will always have at least X values

I've been banging my head against this one for a while without much success. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59637860/partition-tuple-of-numbers-into-chunks i will make this as duplicate

Comment: what have you tried so far ?  the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example